# Using Joi.ref with regex in Joi

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm struggling to figure out why I can't use `Joi.ref()` to set the regex values. I'm getting errors like: `joi regex must be a RegExp`. I've tested my Regex and it works.

How do I pass the regex as context to the schema?

I've tried wrapping values in toString, then using RegExp to no avail. I think it's to do with the formatting of the Regex.

**Joi Schema:**

```
var Schema = Joi.object({
  includeCharacters: Joi.string()
    .max(10)
    .regex(new RegExp(Joi.ref("$regexEC1")), {
      invert: true,
    })
    .optional()
    .allow("")
});
```

**JS Function**

```
var regexEC = new RegExp(`/[THE]/i`);

var validationErrors = Schema.validate(
          this.settings,
          {
            context: { regexEC1: regexEC },
          }
        );
```